# Cobertura Can Not Recognize Java 1.7 Diamond Operator

Tags: java, cobertura

When I build my project at Bamboo I get that error:

```
build   30-Nov-2013 17:26:36    [cobertura] WARN  [main] net.sourceforge.cobertura.reporting.ComplexityCalculator - JavaNCSS got an error while parsing the java file /home/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/XXX-YYY-JOB1/src/main/java/com/ccc/xxx/aaa/BB.java
build   30-Nov-2013 17:26:36    ParseException in STDIN
build   30-Nov-2013 17:26:36    Last useful checkpoint: "com.ccc.xxx.aaa.BB.file(String)"
build   30-Nov-2013 17:26:36    Encountered " ">" "> "" at line 115, column 15.
build   30-Nov-2013 17:26:36    Was expecting one of:
build   30-Nov-2013 17:26:36        "boolean" ...
build   30-Nov-2013 17:26:36        "byte" ...
build   30-Nov-2013 17:26:36        "char" ...
build   30-Nov-2013 17:26:36        "double" ...
build   30-Nov-2013 17:26:36        "float" ...
build   30-Nov-2013 17:26:36        "int" ...
build   30-Nov-2013 17:26:36        "long" ...
build   30-Nov-2013 17:26:36        "short" ...
build   30-Nov-2013 17:26:36        <IDENTIFIER> ...
build   30-Nov-2013 17:26:36        "?" ...
build   30-Nov-2013 17:26:36        "boolean" ...
build   30-Nov-2013 17:26:36        "char" ...
build   30-Nov-2013 17:26:36        "byte" ...
build   30-Nov-2013 17:26:36        "short" ...
build   30-Nov-2013 17:26:36        "int" ...
build   30-Nov-2013 17:26:36        "long" ...
build   30-Nov-2013 17:26:36        "float" ...
build   30-Nov-2013 17:26:36        "double" ...
build   30-Nov-2013 17:26:36        <IDENTIFIER> ...
build   30-Nov-2013 17:26:36        "?" ...
build   30-Nov-2013 17:26:36        "?" ...
build   30-Nov-2013 17:26:36        "?" ...
build   30-Nov-2013 17:26:36        "?" ...
```

I think that cobertura could not recognize Java 1.7 diamond operator. By the way it does not gives error at my local machine.

**PS:** I think that maven-surefire plugin uses Cobertura. However local computer does not gives that error. On the other hand Bamboo and my computer uses same version of surefire: 2.10

Comment: A web search came up with a lot of SO (and other site) posts about this, specifically [this one](http://sourceforge.net/p/cobertura/patches/104/).

Comment: I use Sonar plugin. I do not get any error at my local. I just get that errors at Bamboo? It is not because of Sonar but cos of maven-surefire plugin uses it.

Comment: Does [this post](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.sonar.general/30433) help?  I don't have experience using Sonar and Cobertura with Java 7, but there appears to be a lot of discussion on this and other forums about this combination.

Comment: You can check my edit to question.

Comment: I used JaCoCo for Java 7 due to same issues.

Comment: What version of cobertura are you using? This has been resolved in 2.0 and later versions of cobertura. The maven plugin version needs to be 2.6.

Comment: Actually I don't explicitly use any of them. I think that Bamboo runs mvn:site and it uses Cabertura by default?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in my project. It's resolved by the version 2.6 of the corbertura plugin.
In my POM.xml, i have :

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
   <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.6</version>
</plugin>
```

Bye.

Comment: Were you using JDK 1.7 as well? If yes, which update?